# Get all lat/lon points inside a bounding box area

Tags: python, python-3.x, latitude-longitude, bounding-box, shapely

I am able to generate a southwest-northeast bounding box from latitude, longitude and radius.
How could I possibly get all the points within that bounding box area?

I have tried creating a `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` object thinking I can extract the points with `polygon.coords` or `polygon.interiors`. I generated the polygon like this:

```
import shapely.geometry as sg

bbox = (55.74341900255196, 37.5950436686672, 55.79737829890708, 37.69096949784429)
polygon = sg.box(*bbox, ccw=True)
```

But nothing could possibly give all points inside the box.

Comment: What do you mean by all points in the area? There's an infinite number of points within a polygon.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options:

**The naive solution** - pass your bbox to a function that returns True if a point's lat, lng values between the bbox values

**Pro** - Computationally cheap

**Con** - Not accurate (Doesn't take into account the curves of the earth)

```
def isin_box(lat, lng, bbox):
    
   x1, x2, x3, x4 = bbox
    
   within = False
    
   if x2 < lat < x4:
      if x1 < lng < x3:
         within = True
    
   return within

isin_box(55.77037811279297,37.64223791838213, bbox)
True
```

**The accurate solution** - use shapely within operation to check if a point object lies in the bbox  polygon:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

bbox = (55.74341900255196, 37.5950436686672, 55.79737829890708, 37.69096949784429)
polygon = sg.box(*bbox, ccw=True)
Point(55.77037811279297,37.64223791838213).within(polygon)
True
```

**Pro** - Accurate

**Con** - Computationally expensive